# SQL - Finding all instances of a number in a table in one column and displaying data from another column in that row

Tags: php, sql, reference, numbers

I have a database with id numbers from 1 all the way to around 5000. Each page displays data from it's corresponding row based on page hashes using ajax to load the relevant data into each div. Each row has a varchar column that tells what other items are relevant. On each page, I would like to cross index the whole table to find instances of the relevant id in other entries and display the title of that entry from the table with a link (which will be generated automatically using a script). For example, if my id is 346, I would like to parse the 'relevant' column for any entries that contain a reference to #346 and display the data from the 'title' column of that row for each instance found in the table.

So, a selection of my database looks like this.

```
+-------------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+
| id (INT)          | title (VCHAR)  | author (VCHAR)   | relevant (VCHAR) |
+-------------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+
| 346               | title A        | name             | See #2 and #24   |
| 347               | title B        | name             | See #789         |
| 348               | title C        | name             | See #1 and #346  |
| 349               | title D        | name             | See #34 and #224 |
| 340               | title E        | name             | See #34 and #346 |
| 341               | title F        | name             | See #13 and #87  |
| 342               | title G        | name             | See #346 and #600|
| 343               | title H        | name             | See #346 and #808|
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, based on my url hash, which would be #346, I should see output into a div that looks like this

```
See also:
Title C    Title E     Title G     Title H
```

What is the best method for doing this? Would it be better to use some other reference besides a url hash since I'm already pulling the id from the database using it?

---

Based on the answers, it seems I should start with reworking my database, which might take a while since I've already got a lot of the data set, but I want to do it right, so I'm going to come back to this later. Thank you for the insight!

So I should start with something like this?

```
+----+--------+------+----------------------+-----+-----+-----+
|id  |title   |author|relevant              |ref1 |ref2 |ref3 |
+----+--------+------+----------------------+-----+-----+-----+
| 346| title A| name | See (ref1) and (ref2)| 2   | 24  |     |
| 347| title B| name | See (ref1)           | 798 |     |     |
| 348| title C| name | See (ref1) and (ref2)| 1   | 346 |     |
| 349| title D| name | See (ref1) and (ref2)| 34  | 224 |     |
| 340| title E| name | See (ref1) and (ref2)| 34  | 346 |     |
| 341| title F| name | See (ref1) and (ref2)| 13  | 87  |     |
| 342| title G| name | See (ref1) and (ref2)| 346 | 600 |     |
| 343| title H| name | See (ref1) and (ref2)| 346 | 808 |     |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: _"Each row has a varchar column that tells what other items are relevant"_ - There's your issue. You should read about [database normalization](https://www.essentialsql.com/database-normalization/). You should have a separate table where you add the references (with two columns: `id, ref_id` and then one row per reference). Then you can use JOIN to get the reference data. The way you know have it doesn't just make it hard to search what you want, you also can't utilize indexes, which will impact performance.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful reading! I'm going to rework everything and see if I can get a fresh start on this later.

Answer (score -1):

As mentionned in the comment by @M.Eriksson, your database structure is wrong and will lead you to bad performances.

Now, if you need to keep your current data structure and if performances are not critical, you can sort this out by doing one more query for each results :

- Loop over each of your articles, use a regex to extract all the #id of column relevant into an array.
- Build a SQL query based on that array :

  SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE id=id1 OR id=id2 OR id=id3...

(that can be easily done using the function `implode`)